# How to remove Spam link from website?

Tags: code-injection, spam, google-search-console

Google webmaster says there is a spam link in my website but i can not find any thing while browsing cpanel or it says page not found while visiting that link.[image]

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. It's impossible to know the cause based only on what you've provided.

Comment: The Google message says "...spamming search results" NOT spam.  They see your pages as a bad attempt at "Search Engine Optimization" that they are treating as junk content.